# vim: E14 Invalid Address, reassign variable inside if statement

Tags: vim

I'm trying to make my tab spacing dependent on file type. But I get the error `E14 Invalid Address` on `line 3`.

```
function! Tabs()
  let t = 4
  if (&filetype ==? 'yaml') || (&filetype ==? 'yml')
    t = 2
  endif

  " size of a hard tabstop
  let &tabstop=t

  " size of an "indent"
  let &shiftwidth=t

  " a combination of spaces and tabs are used to simulate tab stops at a width
  " other than the (hard)tabstop
  let &softtabstop=t
endfunction
autocmd! BufReadPost,BufNewFile * call Tabs()
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must always use `:let` to assign a value to a variable:

```
let t = 2
```

Note: although it is not strictly required, it is somewhat customary to put spaces around the operator for `:let`:

```
let &foo = 1
```

And it is mandatory to avoid spaces for `:set`:

```
set foo=1
```

Comment: Avoiding spaces around `=` for `set` is pretty much mandatory.